# missing packages

Tags: android, package

I'm a beginner in android and i tried running some code I got from the net.
Android can't import the following:

> import android.net.http.EventHandler;
>
> import android.net.http.Headers;
>
> import android.net.http.RequestQueue;

Are these packages not included in the sdk? Where can I get these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those *classes* are in the [Android Open Source Project (AOSP) Sources](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/net/http;h=566da03903f7c9d2f3cce4c7d3794c981ede56e6;hb=HEAD) but they're [not included in the SDK from Google](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/http/package-summary.html).  If you really want those classes you could download the source tree with `git`.

However, since those classes aren't easily available you'd be better off looking for some different sample code to run.

Answer (score 1):

Some tutorials out there are based on older versions of Android and haven't been updated as the SDK changes, this is probably what you are running into....[similar thread](http://www.anddev.org/http_post_web_services_in_android-t299.html) where people have issues with same imports, there also a supposed work around [here](http://www.anddev.org/http_post_sdk_10-t3493.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs, those classes aren't part of the SDK.  If you're looking for classes to interact with HTTP, you might take a look at the docs for [org.apache.http](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html).